# Instantiating an object to make code faster

Tags: java

I have a Utils class that loads a large list of Strings (a static variable) and defines a function that uses this list.

I use this function in another class Solution. Currently, I am calling Utils.my_function every time I use it (in a big for loop, so it is called thousands times). Would it be faster if I instantiate a Utils in Solution? (would the list of words defined in Utils be defined only one time?)

Comment: Hopefully you'll get decent help soon, but as for me, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around just what it is you're trying to do. Some code and more detail would help me at any rate.

Comment: If the list of strings is static, why not make it `static` and make `my_function` static, too? Then you could just cache the result in a private static variable after the first call.

Comment: I can't put my code, but basically, I have a function in a class Solution that reads a text file. For every line in this file, I have to perform an operation on this file to remove some words: for each line: call Utils.my_function(line) that removes some words if they are present. The list of words to remove is defined in Utils. I would like to know whether it is better to instantiate a Utils in Solution so as to avoid to create the list of words for every call of Utils.my_function. Instead, I would have Utils util which would load this list once and call util.my_function

Comment: Depends on how you "load" the list and how you trigger the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a large list of Strings (a static variable)
>   ...
>   would the list of words defined in Utils be defined only one time?

By definition, a static variable is loaded only once. So it's already the fastest you can do.

EDIT : the devs who code Java are smart. It's very likely that the JVM can detect your array is accessed very often, and will optimise its operations, whether it is a static or instance variable. However I cannot give you more information than this, and maybe some Java experts can give you a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as already pointed out that `static` is only called once anyway. Another thing you can do is batch processing -- http://java.dzone.com/articles/batch-processing-best

Instead of looping by each line -- call a set of lines at a time then perform your functions, then move to the next set, etc. You would need to profile your app to see how many lines would yield a good response for the app.